# Update field with plain javascript in the Offline Chat Form

Tags: lightning, aura

Currently we are trying to update a field where we do not have access to the Aura code / controller to update the value of a field.
Source HTML:

```
<select class="Language__c slds-style-select select" size="1" aria-describedby="" id="Language__c" data-aura-rendered-by="362:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="7">
    <!--render facet: 363:0-->
    <option label="- Aucun -" value="__default_none__" class="optionClass">- Aucun -</option>
    <option label="Nederlands (België)" value="nl_BE" class="optionClass">Nederlands (België)</option>
    <option label="Frans (België)" value="fr_BE" class="optionClass">Frans (België)</option>
    <option label="Nederlands (Nederland)" value="nl_NL" class="optionClass">Nederlands (Nederland)</option>
</select>
```

I have tried the following:

```
$('#Language__c').val( 'fr_BE' ); 
$('#Language__c').trigger('change');
$('#Language__c').trigger('blur');
```

But when submitting the form, the original default value is submitted.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're trying to write some JS to do it, and that you correctly linked jQuery.  
Have you tried `$('#Language__c').value( 'fr_BE' ); `?

Comment: .value doesn't exist, but I have tried $('#Language__c')[0].value =  'fr_BE';